# How to add together the total sum of two columns in one table with same I'd appearing for both

Tags: mysql

An example is this; 
 I have a table called match results which gives me the points of individual players(divided into home and away)

Like I have a columns called

```
ID       Playerhome   Playeraway Homepoints away points


1        P01          P02        4          7
2        P03          p04        5          6
3        P05          P06        3          8
4        P07          p08        2          9

5        P02          P04        8          3
6        P06          P08        1          10
```

So I want a query that will add the sum of  the column homePoints and sum of awayPoints for each individual player,  as you can see player p02 appeared in both home and away,  so I want it to sum both records for each of the Players...

So the query result will be like:

```
Playerid    Total points

Po1         4
Po2         15
Po3         5
Po4         9
```

I was able to get the first result,but as a result of further normalization
I removed both the home player and away player and then store their points in another table rather....so now I have something like this:

```
playerfixture:
playerHOME       playerAway
p1               p2
p3               p4
p2               p3
```

and then the next table stores their points

```
points
homepoints        away points
4                 7
8                 3
9                 2
```

So now, please am asking for a query that will sum the points for the 2 columns in the points table and display it alongside the player who it referes to

So the result of the query would be like

```
result:
player    totalpoints
p1        4
p2        16
p3        10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  player, SUM(points)
FROM    (
        SELECT  playerhome player, homepoints points
        FROM    mytable
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  playeraway player, awaypoints points
        FROM    mytable
        ) q
GROUP BY
        player
```

Comment: thanks alot man...the query actually got me the correct result i was looking for

Comment: Thank you very much for the first reply, and now,i have separated the home and away player id from the table which had them all together, am now asking how i can get the same result as the first question i asked but this time around 2 tables are queried